# TLS certificate rotation for an orderer node - Cryptogen to Fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have been working on *rotating Orderer node certs* from **cryptogen** to **Fabric CA**.
I have been following the official documentation here-
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/raft_configuration.html

Below are the steps that i have tried till now -

1. generate new certs with **fabric CA* server for each of the nodes.
2. update the `configtx.yaml` *msp* path with the new *msp* path created for orderer.
3. create new `Orderer.json` based on the new the `configtx.yaml`
4. update the system channel with new certs using *jq*.

Currently i am getting an issue while i try to update the system channel 'testchainid'. The error seen is -

> Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'testchainid': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: invalid mod_policy for element [Group]  /Channel/Application: mod_policy not set

Sharing the steps performed on the peer cli:

```
peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o orderer.org.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA

configtxlator proto_decode --input config_block.pb --type common.Block | jq .data.data[0].payload.data.config > config.json

# Find the diff between current config and new config, then output a new json file
jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {"OrdererMSP":.[1]}}}}}' config.json Orderer.json > modified_config.json

# add fabric ca tls certs

jq 'del(.channel_group.groups.Orderer.values.ConsensusType.value.metadata.consenters[])' modified_config.json > modified_config_1.json

#new ca cert for orderer to update system channel
cert1=$(base64 /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/org.com/orderer/tls-msp/signcerts/cert.pem | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g')

#new ca cert for orderer1 to update in system channel
cert2=$(base64 /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/org.com/orderer1/tls-msp/signcerts/cert.pem | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g')

#new ca cert for orderer2 to update in system channel
cert3=$(base64 /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/org.com/orderer2/tls-msp/signcerts/cert.pem | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g')

#update the new certs on to channel
jq '.channel_group.groups.Orderer.values.ConsensusType.value.metadata.consenters += [{"client_tls_cert": "'$cert1'", "host": "orderer.org.com", "port": 7050, "server_tls_cert": "'$cert1'"}] | .channel_group.groups.Orderer.values.ConsensusType.value.metadata.consenters += [{"client_tls_cert": "'$cert2'", "host": "orderer1.org.com", "port": 7050, "server_tls_cert": "'$cert2'"}] | .channel_group.groups.Orderer.values.ConsensusType.value.metadata.consenters += [{"client_tls_cert": "'$cert3'", "host": "orderer2.org.com", "port": 7050, "server_tls_cert": "'$cert3'"}] ' modified_config_1.json > modified_config_2.json

# Converts config.json into config.pb
configtxlator proto_encode --input config.json --type common.Config --output config.pb

# Converts modified_config.pb into modified_config.json
configtxlator proto_encode --input modified_config.json --type common.Config --output modified_config.pb

# Converts modified_config.pb into modified_config.json
configtxlator proto_encode --input modified_config_1.json --type common.Config --output modified_config_1.pb

# Converts modified_config.pb into modified_config.json
configtxlator proto_encode --input modified_config_2.json --type common.Config --output modified_config_2.pb

# Calculates the delta between modified_config.json config.json then output
configtxlator compute_update --channel_id $CHANNEL_NAME --original config.pb --updated modified_config_2.pb --output Orderer_ca_update.pb

configtxlator proto_decode --input Orderer_ca_update.pb --type common.ConfigUpdate | jq . > Orderer_ca_update.json

echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"testchainid", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":'"$(cat Orderer_ca_update.json)"'}}}' | jq . > Orderer_ca_update_in_envelope.json

configtxlator proto_encode --input Orderer_ca_update_in_envelope.json --type common.Envelope --output Orderer_ca_update_in_envelope.pb

peer channel signconfigtx -f Orderer_ca_update_in_envelope.pb

peer channel update -f Orderer_ca_update_in_envelope.pb -c $CHANNEL_NAME -o orderer.org.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA
```

Any help on how to fix the issue would be much appreciated.